# How to complete object creation after I deserialize it

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

It is the first time I deal with Java serialization, and I have a problem I can't solve.

I have an ArrayList of objects of a custom class `Square`. I marked `Square` as `Serializable` and I have some fields which are actually serializable and some which I don't want to be serialized (I marked them as`transient`). By the way when I deserialize the object I want to fill these fields with my custom logic.

For example I serialized fields `int height` and `int width` but I marked as `transient` field `int area`, so when I deserialize my object I want to calculate `area = height * width` (of course this is just an example, what I have to do is more complex, for example I have to initialize some fields by calling their constructor and by passing it some fields I previously deserialized`).

To do so I implemented in my class something like this:

```
protected void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        stream.defaultReadObject();

        //do other stuff to finalize the construction of the object I've just deserialized
}
```

The problem is that it seems that all the code after `stream.defaultReadObject();` doesn't run.
Indeed if I try to debug the program I can observe that all the fields marked as transient are still `null` after the deserialization.

Last but not least the class of the objects of the arrayList I have to serialize has subclasses. I never instantiate an object of the superclass, but only objects of subclasses. In some subclasses I've overridden the base method `readObject(ObjectInputStream)` in this way:

```
    protected void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        super.readObject(stream);

        //do other stuff specific for the subclass
}
```

Moreover I'm pretty sure that the methods I use to serialize and deserialize objects work, indeed all the fields which are NOT `transient` are perfectly restored when I serialize and then deserialize an object.

I'm sorry if the question is confusing, if you need explainations I'll add them!

---

### **SOME CODE**

**Deserialization method:**

```
 public static <T extends Serializable> T deserialize(Context context, String fileName) {
    T object = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = context.openFileInput(fileName);
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
        object = (T) objectInputStream.readObject();
        objectInputStream.close();
        fileInputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException ioExc) {
        ioExc = new IOException("Cannot open the file specified);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfExc){
        cnfExc = new ClassNotFoundException("Class not found");
    }

    return object;
}
```

**Class with the list to serialize:**

```
public Class listClass{
    public static ArrayList<AAA> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    //...
}
```

**Class where I deserialize the list:**

```
listClass.myList = deserialize(getContext(), "myFile");
if (listClass == null){
    listClass = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**Class AAA:**

```
public Class AAA implements Serializable{
    protected int field1;
    protected double field2;
    protected BBB bbb;

    //constructor...

    private finalizeDeserialization(){
        this.bbb = new BBB(field2);
    }

    protected void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        stream.defaultReadObject();

        finalizeDeserialization();
    }
}
```

**Class BBB:**

```
public Class bbb{
    public BBB(double aDouble){
        //...
    }
//...
}
```

**Class ACC:**

```
public Class ACC extends AAA{
    private double field3;
    private BBB cbb;

    //constructor...

    protected void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        super.readObject(stream);

        cbb = new BBB(field3);
    }
}
```

Comment: `"For example I serialized fields int height and int width but I marked as transient field int area"` -- you shouldn't even have a field called area as that makes for brittle code and is asking for trouble, should area get out of sync with height and width. Rather your class should have a `getArea()` method that calculates this value based on the current height and width.

Comment: Also, if your serialization/deserialization is not working, and you're asking for help, don't assume that any part of your code is working (unless you have tests that prove this). Instead create a simplified code version that reproduces the problem for us, a valid [mcve]. For my money, I'd prefer to use text-readable serialization such as XML/JAXB or JSON.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry but it is the first example which came on my mind to simplify my problem. Real code doesn't deal with polygons.

Comment: Then please look at the [mcve] construct and try to show us compilable and runnable *real* code that demonstrates the problem, code small enough to post in your question in its entirety.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I think seriaization and deserialization methods work, because non-transient fields are restored. I think that if they don't work then all the fields should have problems.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I added some code, it is not my code but maybe it can help. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't compile nor run for me, so I'm out of luck

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels what doesn't run? Moreover don't you have an idea of where I'm wrong (not the code in the post but my main question)? I mean, is the "logic" of what I'm doing correct? Or is putting some methods calls after the 'defaultReadObject()' useless? Any suggestions is welcome, maybe it will lead me on the right way. Thanks.

Comment: What doesn't run? Everything as you've posted incomplete non-compilable code. Please read or re-read the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) again if you're desiring as prompt and complete a solution as possible. To get us to quickly best and fully understand the problem, I'm asking you to create a new and complete program, one that we can copy and paste in one fell swoop into our IDE's, that will compile without alteration for us, that runs for us, that reproduces the problem, and (again) that's small enough to post in the question and not in a link. This is asking a lot, but so R U

Comment: Marco - what HC is asking for is an MCVE.  Something he can cut-and-paste directly into a files, compile with `javac`, and run with `java`.  He doesn't want to spend 15 minutes filling in all the bits (1) that are needed to make your code snippets compileable / runnable. (1 - and then another 2 hours back and forth because he made assumptions that are different to what you are actually doing ...)

Comment: Yep, exactly as @StephenC says. Understand that there is no requirement that you include an MCVE in your question, and if you can get a decent answer without this, then more power to you, but I *am* saying that creating and posting a decent one will likely greatly increase your chances of getting a very decent answer and quickly. It's all your call of course, and depends on whether someone clever enough sees your question who can figure out your problem without this (and if anyone is, it's Stephen), but barring that, also on how much you need an answer quickly.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I know it can't compile but it is to show you what my program does. I asked some questions on this site and I always wrote code to make others understand my problem... I don't want you to write my code for me, I'd just like to be addressed on the right way, I'm here to learn. I don't think my problem is uncommon for an experienced programmer, but I'm only a rookie. Tomorrow I'll try to write some executable code if nobody can help me (here in Italy it's 2AM). Thanks anyway and sorry.

Comment: The code you posted looks OK.  But clearly is it not the *real* code ... so I can't comment on why *that* doesn't work.  The only suggestion I can make without an MCVE is to check that your custom `readObject` method is actually being called.

Comment: @StephenC I don't know if the code I posted is completely right. Indeed I've read that custom readObject must be private (if not when I deserialize a subclass JVM can't call both readObject methods of the superclass and then the subclass, but instead it overrides the superclass method). Can this be the reason why I have the problem? And again sorry if I haven't posted some executable code. By the way tomorrow I'll check if by declaring them private I'll solve the problem or not.

Comment: *"Indeed I've read that custom readObject must be private"* - the specification doesn't say that.  It is *advisable* to do that ... because nothing apart from the object stream code should be calling the method.

Comment: Actually, I looked at the code ... and it does enforce that the method must be private and nor static.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034748/findbugs-wants-readobject-to-be-private-for-serialization-why

Comment: @StephenC yes, that exactly the question I read too (and also other websites on the web). I also read the documentation and it says nothing about this, but I think that the explaination in the accepted answer makes sense. I'll try as soon as I have a PC available. Thanks

Comment: @StephenC by the way it seems that it must be private, but not static. At least I used private but not static and it worked

Comment: I know.  Did you see my (updated) answer to the other question?

Comment: @StephenC Sorry I didn't notice it was your answer, by the way I read this: _will only recognize  readObject, readObjectNoData and writeObject methods if they are declared as private and static._

Comment: Ooops .... fixed :-)

Comment: @StephenC perfect, thanks a lot!